# If all four angles inside a quadrilateral are defined, how to find the angle of intersection of diagonals of the quadrilateral?

Tags: geometry, quadrilateral

Say, I have a quadrilateral where all four internal angles are defined, say ∠a, ∠b, ∠c, ∠d . This should be enough to determine the shape of the quadrilateral even though its size can be arbitrary.

So if shape of this quadrilateral is defined, we should be able to determine the angle of intersection of its diagonals. Is there any formula for determining the angle of intersection of diagonals for the quadrilateral?

Answer (score 6):

Not possible, because the four internal angles don't determine the shape of a quadrilateral. Consider a square vs. a rectangle.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. So how much minimum information is needed to determine the shape of an "n" sided polygon?

Comment: @VishnuTallapragada Given knowledge of the angles (in some order), I'm guessing $n-2$ consecutive side lengths are sufficient.  But for $n=3$, the angles themselves are enough to determine the shape.

Comment: I would modify that sufficiency condition slightly. If you can render the ratio of any $n-3$ consecutive sides to an adjoining side, you're good.